# Javascript onsubmit not working form when used with "document.getElementById..." in a form

Tags: javascript, html, onsubmit

Friends, I am new to JS and I am trying out something that should have been really simple - I want to display a message in a `<p>` element using document.getElementById when a form is submitted but its not working. However, when I trigger a window.alert onsubmit, it works! Please help! Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>

<p id="one"></p>

<form method="POST" onsubmit="document.getElementById('one').innerHTML='Ok';">

Name:<input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>
```

Comment: When you submit the form, page gets refreshed hence you can not view the updated `DOM`..Edit: `onsubmit="document.getElementById('one').innerHTML='Ok';return false;"` __return false;__ will prevent form submission..   Just to demonstrate..

Comment: @creative i tried your example and works, appears the text "Ok" in the p tag. Later page is refreshed as Rayon said

Comment: That's because form submit refreshes the page. Use `preventDefault()` to prevent page from refreshing and then update your `<p>`. Or if form submit ain't that important, use a input button and not submit.